# Copy game data from one PS4 to another?

Tags: ps4

I purchased a digital game (Rainbow Six) and now I must download the game data. Can I instead copy the game data from my friend's PS4? He bought the digital version and downloaded the data already.

Can I copy it to my PC and then copy it onto my PS4 ? I know I can download data from my PC but can I copy data from his PS4 to my PC or directly on my PS4?

Comment: Hi Josh, welcome to Arqade! Please don't ask multiple questions in one post. I have edited out your other questions to focus on the core one: if you'd like you're welcome to repost them as separate questions. :). (You can still access the text of them, it's in the revision history: click the 'edited X minutes ago' link to view it). :) Hope this helps and enjoy your day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy data off the PS4 to a external drive, and then copy it back to a PS4 in the same way. However, the game may have restrictions on the saved data. For example, some games won't allow you to use save data from another user account. The only thing to do is give it a try and see if you get an error within the game with trying to load it.

[This PS4 Guide gives instructions on loading data off a USB drive](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/gb/ps4/settings/data_usb.html).