# Is it possible to transfer game data from one account to another on the same PS4?

Tags: ps4, psn, bloodborne

I would like to transfer my progress in Bloodborne from my account to my Dad's account on the same PS4, and continue playing the game on my Dad's account. That's because I have registered myself as a child account though I am 16, and my Dad is the Family Manager. By doing so, I can play the game online through my Dad's account.

Is it possible to continue my current progress in another account on the same console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you cannot do this** because Bloodborne save files are bound to a PSN account.

I've just tried moving around my Bloodborne saves via usb copy method from this question: [Copy game data from one PS4 to another?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/253005/144891) and my second account cannot see saves created by my main account.

Comment: Though I am really disappointed I can't do it